# Does running a relay expose my IP and make me vulnerable to attacks?

Tags: security, relays

I'm running a non exit relay, but I am slightly concerned. My relay information is listed on the Atlas, along with my IP Address. Is this safe? Doesn't it make me an easy target for getting ddosed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as safe as having an external IP address itself: whenever you have it, it is already discoverable. Tor network itself can not be easily DDoS'ed because of it's distributed nature, so there is no practical use at all to DDoS a particular tor node, actually :) Also running a relay is making your network life safer, actually: your traffic is mixed up with relay traffic, and if an adversary will try to snoop on your traffic - his task is a way tougher: relay's traffic must be separated from yours :)